# Pass data into datepicker from input-field using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a form where the user can choose two dates.

To do this, I'm using datepicker.

JavaScript to display the input field:

```js
        let form = document.getElementById("dateform");

        let output = "<div>";
        output +=
          "<input type='text' id='date" + i + "' onFocus='pickdate("+ i +")'><br/>";
        output += "</div>";

        form.innerHTML = output;
```

The "i" is used because I have several things the user can book dates for in a table. So in order to not book the same thing over and over again I've created a loop to give each product a unique id.

```js
      function pickdate(i) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
          date = $("#date" + i).datepicker();
        });
      }
```

Now, this code works. The problem I'm having is that I have to click on the datepicker twice in order for it to show.

The only way I've managed to get the datepicker to pop up on the first click is by using this:

```js
      $(document).on("focus", "#date1", function () {
        $(this).datepicker();
      });
```

By using this I don't have to call the function in the html either.

I however, here give the "i" value manually in "id="#date1". I need it to be dynamic and come from the product the user clicks on. With JavaScript I can just send the variable like I've done above. But how do I send the "i" value into the function with jQuery?

Thank you.

EDIT:

I tried my best to recreate the problem:

https://codepen.io/leoss/pen/gOKGRML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the same css class to each `<input/>` and remove the `onFocus` like so:

```
let dateOutput += "<div class='booking-dates'>";
  dateOutput +=
    "<input type='text' class='my-date-picker' id='date" + i +"' />;
```

You can initialize all of the date pickers at once with something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.my-date-picker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function (date) {

    }
  });
});
```

You might not even need the `id` attribute at all.

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/zigdawgydawg/pen/xxzXryG) that combines your example with my example above and shows both how to initialize an arbitrary number of datepickers at once and how to find the `i` of the datepicker where a date was picked.

Comment: thank you. I've tried this, unfortunately it doesn't work. The datepicker doesn't show up at all. I also need the "i"-value sent into the function because there are several products a user can book. And in order for each product to get a unique id, I have to use the "i"-variabel so it's not only the first product that always get booked. The data is fetched from a database.

Comment: It would be great if you could create a [Minimum Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that others can reproduce the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Regarding passing the `i` into the `onSelect` function, you could set a [data-i attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp) on each input and then access it inside the `onSelect` function with something like `var i = $(this).data('i');`

Comment: I will try to recreate the problem. I'll update the post when I've done it.

Comment: I added a codepen now. I hope it'll describe the problem better.

Comment: I added a codepen that was forked from your codepen. Hopefully it will help you see how to implement what I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I made it work with your code. Thanks alot for taking your time. I've been stuck on this for hours!